# QGIS API to determine number of walls an AP intersects

Tags: qgis

We are trying to identify QGIS API which can determine where all does a ray of signal intersects in a given room. See image for reference.

[image]

What we are looking for as result is "the lat lng of all the points on the wall where the ray intersects the wall".

Any ideas / pointers will be great help.

Comment: In the reference image, points already exists. If they exists, it's simple to extract their coordinates. If not, specify in your question what are your input data (coordinates of the source signal, walls as polylines, coordinate system, are rays sent in all directions or at certain angles, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a [raycasting function for PostGIS](https://github.com/iboates/ST_RayCast) that could help. If you put your data in a database you could make a [virtual layer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jJeae7PJVv4) from an SQL query using this function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the image you provided, I'm assuming you have the following data:

- Exterior wall of the room, as a polygon layer
- Signal rays, as a line layer
- Interior walls of the room, as a line layer (or whatever the green and blue lines represent)

**How to extract the coordinates where the signal rays intersect the walls of the room:**

1. Convert the exterior wall polygon(s) to lines, using the Polygons to Lines tool (in the Processing Toolbox). (If your walls are already lines, you can skip this step.)
2. Copy and paste the interior wall lines into the exterior wall lines layer. If you prefer, you can skip this step and instead perform each of the following steps twice.
3. Use the Line Intersections tool (in the Processing Toolbox) on the wall lines and ray lines layers. This creates a point layer of all the intersection points.
4. Use the Add Geometry Attributes tool (Vector menu > Geometry Tools) to add the x and y coordinates to the point layer.
5. Export the point layer in CSV format. Now you have all the intersection coordinates in a spreadsheet.